# Where are class extensions placed in an MVVM pattern?

Tags: mvvm

I am new to this and still trying to get a feel for the best way to do things with MVVM. I can't find an answer with Google.

For convenience, I have created extensions on multiple custom classes, e.g.,

```
 public static AppointmentLabel ToLabel(this textblockPatient tbp)
    {
        return tbp.appointmentlabel;
    }
```

In my MVVM model, I have placed these extensions in the Model as they seem to convert one source of information into another. However, some of the custom classes are UserControls and live in the View.  Doing it this way would require the Model to "know" something about the View, as the above textblockPatient is a UserControl.

How is this done within a MVVM pattern? Are extensions considered to be an exception to the pattern?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's not MVVM, so it doesn't matter what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is not a mvvm related thing. I would suggest that you put your extension classes near to the classes they extend. By doing it so you reach some level of cohesion. Sometimes it make sense to put the extensions in a seperate project. For example if you know you want need that extensions all the time and you want to have a small codebase or faster compile time.